# combining different actions into one sinlge action

Tags: animation, workflow, actions

i have two different actions one is "reload" and other one is "m100_reload" as shown in the picture below.Now i want a one complete action  like  "m100_reload". How i can combine these two reload action to make it a single one reload animation.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIxbI.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmdT7.png

Comment: you can either do it in the NLA (click on the Dope Sheet Push Down button and these actions will appear as strips), or you can copy paste the keyframes from an action to another. In the first case it may create some jumps in the 3D scene, in the second case it may create interpolation that you don't want and that you'll need to correct.

Comment: ok thnx,but i have two armature one for the hand and for the gun,do i have to push down the actions on both armatures

Comment: if the hand is supposed to control the gun, you'd better use another method, like parenting the hand to the gun with a Child Of Constraint, then animate the gun (you won't need to animate the hand as it will follow the gun)